# How to import django template library globally?

Tags: python, django, internationalization

I have a main template `main.html` from which I extend from, I want to load the i18m library on it or globally to evade using `{% load i18n %}` everywhere.

How i could do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is unfortunately not possible. See the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/templates/language/#custom-libraries-and-template-inheritance) :

> When you load a custom tag or filter library, the tags/filters are
> only made available to the current template – not any parent or child
> templates along the template-inheritance path.
>
> For example, if a template foo.html has {% load humanize %}, a child
> template (e.g., one that has {% extends "foo.html" %}) will not have
> access to the humanize template tags and filters. The child template
> is responsible for its own {% load humanize %}.
>
> **This is a feature for the sake of maintainability and sanity.**